# Rest API Best Practice - Single action and Bulk

Tags: rest, api

Let my server have the ability to perform an action called 'A'.
Now, My server needs to have an extra ability to perform bulk 'A' actions.

The route on the server is:
`/entity/:entityId/'A'/:'A'Id`

Adding the bulk ability faced me with two approaches:

1) Exposing 2 routes to each method:
`/entity/:entityId/'A'/:'A'Id` and
`/entity/:entityId/'A'` with a list of 'A' ids in the request's body.

2) Drop the `'A'Id` paramater and add a query parameter to the first route called `bulk` with boolean value:
`/entity/:entityId/'A'/?bulk=boolean`
And if `bulk == true` look for `'A'Id[]` at the request's body.
else if `bulk == false` look for `id` entry at the request's body.

I'm feeling that the 1st approach is better, I'd love to hear thoughts, or maybe a very different approach.

Any opinion is blessed to hear,
Thanks.

Comment: Most of the time it’s best to avoid bulk actions. For example, if you’re trying to create/update/delete 100 records in a single request, do 100 API calls. Error handling becomes a pain when attempting to validate and save 100 things in 1 request and communicate the errors back. Also, if it’s 100 requests, you can do the requests in parallel in javascript (I think the browser will limit you to like 5 open connections at a time), load balancing amongst multiple servers. The total time to save 100 in parallel is faster than 100 synchronous, and you won’t risk timing out.

Comment: The only time Rails’s guides offer a solution to a bulk save, is through a parent object via accepts_nested_attribute_for. Typically the Rails Best Practice around Bulk is to not, which is why the routers don’t have a default option for this like they to `resource` and `resources`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: As @Nate already mentioned, REST's and/or HTTP's strength aren't the handling of bulk operations actually. Not only are bulk operations not recommendable in terms of error handling, but also as you won't benefit from caching HTTP is explicitly setup for. Usually non-safe operations performed on a resource will lead to an eviction of any cached responses for that URI; the URI here is the de facto cache-key. Using a different endpoint for managing resources will therefore not lead to such cached responses being evicted and will likely return outdated information to clients as a consequence

Answer (score 1):

Query params are good for `GET` methods like:

```
curl -X GET host.com/megacorp/employee?employee_id[]=1&employee_id[]=2
```

But for `POST` and `PUT` methods it's better to use something like this:

```
curl -XPOST host.com/megacorp/employee/_bulk -d '{"data":[
    {"id":"1", "name": "John Doe"},
    {"id":"2", "name": "Jane Doe"}
]}'
```

And to `POST` or `PUT` 1 resource - simply provide 1 object in request, like:

```
curl -XPUT host.com/megacorp/employee/1 -d '{
    "name": "JOHN DOE"
},'
```